# Index that picks up on example numbers, not page numbers

Tags: indexing, linguistics, expex

I am producing some glossed linguistic texts in a Native American language.  The sentences are labeled as, e.g., (2.3)—meaning “text 2, sentence 3”—and I’d like the index to pick up on these numbers, rather than page numbers.  In terms of the picture below, I’d like:

> Bratwurst, (2.1)
>
> Sauerkraut, (2.2)

as opposed to what’s shown (Bratwurst, 2; Sauerkraut, 2).

How can I achieve this?

[image]

I’m using a version of expex for the example numbers.  It's too long to include here, but I can email it to any interested parties.

---

*Clarification.  I know how to label examples (by putting e.g., `<label>` after `\ex`) and how to call labels at a later point (`\getref{label}`).  This questions isn't about example labelling however: I don't want to have to manually link *cabbage* to, say, `\getref{Sauerkraut}`, `\getref{Kohl}`, `\getref{Wirsing}`.  I want to piggyback off `makeindex` to produce an index that lists example numbers instead of page numbers.

---

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{expex-x2} 
\usepackage{expexchapno}

\lingset{aboveexskip=0pt,glspace=1em plus .5em minus.2em,   
glrightskip=0pt plus 8em,aboveglftskip=0pt,glneveryline={\it},   
glstyle=nlevel,everygl={\hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1},   
exnotype=chapter.arabic}

\usepackage{makeidx}     
\makeindex

\begin{document}     

\gathertags

\chapter{First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\ex Bratwurst --- this example is followed by \verb"\index{Bratwurst}"
\xe \index{Bratwurst} 

\ex Sauerkraut --- this example is followed by
\verb"\index{Sauerkraut}" \xe \index{Sauerkraut}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Chapter 13 (Referring to examples and labeled parts of examples) of the [ExPex documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf) provides some solutions. AFAIK `\index` is meant to refer to page numbers only.

Comment: As another German, I am also deeply shocked about your selection of words concerning Native American Language;-)

Comment: The lineno package will compute (and usually display) line numbers.   \linelablel{} creates a number which can be displayed using ref{}.  \renewcommand\LineNumber{\relax} will (probably) turn off the display.

Comment: I got it!  You modify \thepage to format page numbers the way you want them in the index, and modify the footer to NOT use \thepage.  Use \arabic{page} instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Are you suggesting: (a) make the index pick up on line number; (b) make the line number counter pick up on example numbers?

Comment: @Christian, Henri: Maybe the mystery language is Pennsylvania Dutch: it's sort of nativized American

Comment: Sorry about lineno.  I wasn't sure what expex was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Longer post

Please allow me to share my findings with you. I've divided my answer into three parts: no traffic, one-way traffic and two-way traffic, each part resulting in its own compilable TeX file.

I have used [Xindy](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/) because [MakeIndex](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/makeindex/) is rather limited for non-English languages. On the other hand, I am using rather old [`makeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx) package, but I would recommend to use the [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) package because we could save one I/O write slot in the last part. I wanted to compare methods, I used that way.

I am using `lualatex` to process the TeX files, but any major `latex` engine can be used.

---

> No transportation: remarks on the `mal-expex-1.tex` file

As it was already pointed out on it, we can redefine `\@wrindex` as it is the key part called by the `\index` command. We can store the information directly by calling for `\ep@rawexnoprint`, see line 19 in the first file. That's the command the [`expex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expex) package uses to store information.

Next problem is how to notify the index processor about number dot number location. Xindy uses location class for this purpose, it uses several of them and we can create a new one. It can be done by `define-location-class` plus we define accompanying `markup-locref` for this new class, in addition to that we are adding parentheses. The last step would be to define the order of new location classes, with your permission, I will show you later how it can be done.

We run:

> lualatex mal-expex-1.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -M expex-1 -L general -C utf8 mal-expex-1.idx
>   lualatex mal-expex-1.tex

The content of the `mal-expex-1.idx` file is as follows:

```
\indexentry{Bratwurst}{2.1}
\indexentry{Sauerkraut}{2.2}
\indexentry{Striz}{2.3}
\indexentry{Oldman}{2.4}
\indexentry{Sauerkraut}{2.5}
```

I enclose the TeX code and a preview of three cropped pages. As we can see from the last page, this is the requested form, but *Houston, we have a problem!* Once we want clickable version of our document, the index cross-references are not working.

```
% run: *latex mal-expex-1.tex
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{aboveexskip=0pt,glspace=1em plus .5em minus.2em,   
glrightskip=0pt plus 8em,aboveglftskip=0pt,glneveryline={\it},   
glstyle=nlevel,everygl={\hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1},   
exnotype=chapter.arabic}
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{expex-1.xdy}
;; expex-1.xdy
(define-location-class "expexnumber" ("arabic-numbers" :sep "." "arabic-numbers"))
(markup-locref :open "(" :close ")" :class "expexnumber")
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\ep@rawexnoprint}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack#1%
}%End of \def\@wrindex...
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
%\gathertags
\chapter{First chapter}
Some initial text.
\chapter{Second chapter}
The first approach.
\ex Bratwurst --- this example is followed by \index{Bratwurst} \xe
\ex Sauerkraut --- this example is followed by \index{Sauerkraut} \xe
\ex By \index{Striz} \xe
\ex By \index{Oldman} \xe
\ex Again \index{Sauerkraut} \xe
%\begingroup
%\def\thispagestyle#1{}%
\printindex
%\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 1: no traffic]

---

> One-way traffic: remarks on the `mal-expex-2.tex` file

Well, I have already opened that Pandora's box, let me inform you how we can save our souls. That major problem brings me to load the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package and explore our further possibilities.

The idea was to use regular cross-references as we know it from `\label`+`\ref`+`\pageref` combination, no matter of what will be typeset in the index location of index entries.

I have redefined the `\@wrindex`, added `|myhyperlink{\ep@rawexnoprint}` which helps us to control the output. The key step was adding `\label{\ep@rawexnoprint}#1` into this command. It stores reference information and prints the reference for us, therefore we don't have to type it twice.

We notify the index processor about a new command by `define-attributes` and we define a new class as in the first example. The result of our efforts is that the number is clickable, the parentheses are not.

There is a small problem as [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is redefining commands that it is clickable but it leads us to the page not to the line where `\index` command was called. If we explore the `mal-expex-2.aux` file further we can see what's going on:

```
\newlabel{2.1}{{1}{2}{Second chapter}{chapter.2}{}}
```

It stored all the necessary information, but it leads to the second chapter. That's not the best result we can achieve here as the title itself could be typeset several pages earlier than the [`expex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expex) examples. Well, we have got some improvement. We are getting error messages from [`xindy`](http://www.xindy.org/) about cross-reference-targets not existing, but we can ignore them, we manage that part by ourselves.

We run these three lines:

> lualatex mal-expex-2.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -M expex-2 -L general -C utf8 mal-expex-2.idx
>   lualatex mal-expex-2.tex

The content of the `mal-expex-2.idx` file is this:

```
\indexentry{Bratwurst|myhyperlink{2.1}}{2.1}
\indexentry{Sauerkraut|myhyperlink{2.2}}{2.2}
\indexentry{Striz|myhyperlink{2.3}}{2.3}
\indexentry{Oldman|myhyperlink{2.4}}{2.4}
\indexentry{Sauerkraut|myhyperlink{2.5}}{2.5}
```

I enclose the TeX code and a preview of the result.

```
% run: *latex mal-expex-2.tex
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{aboveexskip=0pt,glspace=1em plus .5em minus.2em,   
glrightskip=0pt plus 8em,aboveglftskip=0pt,glneveryline={\it},   
glstyle=nlevel,everygl={\hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1},   
exnotype=chapter.arabic}
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\makeindex
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{expex-2.xdy}
;; expex-2.xdy
(define-attributes (("default" "textbf" "textit" "myhyperlink")))
(define-crossref-class "myhyperlink")
(markup-crossref-list :class "myhyperlink" :sep ",\,")
(markup-crossref-layer :open "(\myhyperlink{" :close "})" :class "myhyperlink")
\end{filecontents*}
\def\myhyperlink#1{\hyperref[#1]{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1|myhyperlink{\ep@rawexnoprint}}{\ep@rawexnoprint}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack\label{\ep@rawexnoprint}#1}%
\makeatother%End of \def\@wrindex...

\begin{document}    
%\gathertags
\chapter{First chapter}
Some initial text.
\chapter{Second chapter}
The first approach.
\ex Bratwurst --- this example is followed by \index{Bratwurst} \xe
\ex Sauerkraut --- this example is followed by \index{Sauerkraut} \xe
\ex By \index{Striz} \xe
\ex By \index{Oldman} \xe
\ex Again \index{Sauerkraut} \xe
%\begingroup
%\def\thispagestyle#1{}%
\printindex
%\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 2: one-way traffic]

---

> Two-way traffic: remarks on the `mal-expex-3.tex` file

Once we can improve something, we will. We wish to have clickable version of the document with cross-references leading to the proper locations. Moreover, we can try to have cross-references from both directions. From `\index` to the index and from index entries in index back to its `\index` counterparts. We must bear in mind that index entries are grouped and we may lose some hyperlinks in index, generally speaking.

For this I used a couple of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` commands assuring I provide them unique markers, see lines 40-47 in the code below. It is corrected version, it goes to the original location, but there is no way back. Let's focused on that feature.

I have prepared a new file for next experiments to separate them from regular `idx` file for purpose of this post. I will use `myi` extension (reflects the `idx` file) and `iym` extension (reflects the `ind` file).

The core of this method is to use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` twice: one pair handling one way, the other pair handling the way back. Please see lines 50-65 in the code. I needed to use `\raisebox` to get location from left baseline of the box to the left top corner.

I also prepared a new set of commands for regular use. We can store page numbers (it is a common method; plain arabic number), we can store number of [`expex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expex) example (arabic number dot arabic number wrapped in the parentheses) and chapter number (arabic number wrapped in the brackets). Using this approach, see lines 68-70, we can store almost anything there.

The only remaining thing we must do is to notify [`xindy`](http://www.xindy.org/) about all this. Let's extend our `xdy` style file, please see lines 20-36 in the TeX code.

To make our work easier I have done one more improvement. I have redefined the `\ex...\xe` statements to the form of just `\ex...` by defining the end of the line (`^^M`) as a command and using it afterwards. This step is of course not necessary in production, I just wanted to show you that it can be done and we can save typing of `\xe`.

We run the following four lines:

> lualatex mal-expex-3.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -M expex-3 -L general -C utf8 -o mal-expex-3.ind mal-expex-3.idx
>   xindy -M texindy -M expex-3 -L general -C utf8 -o mal-expex-3.iym mal-expex-3.myi
>   lualatex mal-expex-3.tex

The content of the `mal-expex-3.idx` file is the same as in the second part, because we redefined commands at the TeX level. The content of the `mal-expex-3.myi` file is something new for us and it looks like this:

```
\indexentry{on purpose|malchapter{2-2-1}}{2}
\indexentry{paja|malpage{2-2-2}}{2}
\indexentry{malipivo|malpage{2-2-3}}{2}
\indexentry{next a|malexpex{2.8-2-4}}{2}
\indexentry{more a|malexpex{2.9-2-5}}{2}
\indexentry{next b|malchapter{2-2-6}}{2}
\indexentry{more b|malchapter{2-2-7}}{2}
\indexentry{paja|malexpex{2.12-2-8}}{2}
\indexentry{paja|malchapter{2-2-9}}{2}
```

I enclose the last example and a preview of our efforts.

```
% run: *latex mal-expex-3.tex
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{aboveexskip=0pt,glspace=1em plus .5em minus.2em,   
glrightskip=0pt plus 8em,aboveglftskip=0pt,glneveryline={\it},   
glstyle=nlevel,everygl={\hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1},   
exnotype=chapter.arabic}
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\makeindex
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{expex-3.xdy}
;; expex-3.xdy
(define-location-class "expexnumber" ("arabic-numbers" :sep "." "arabic-numbers"))
(define-location-class "expexchapter" ("arabic-numbers" :sep "."))
(define-location-class-order ("expexnumber" "expexchapter" "arabic-numbers"))

(define-attributes (("malpage" "malexpex" "malchapter" "myhyperlink")))

(define-crossref-class "myhyperlink")
(markup-crossref-list :class "myhyperlink" :sep ",\,")
(markup-crossref-list :open "(\myhyperlink{" :close "})" :class "myhyperlink")

(define-crossref-class "malpage")
(markup-crossref-list :class "malpage" :sep ",\,")
(markup-crossref-layer :open "\myhyper{" :close "}" :class "malpage")

(define-crossref-class "malexpex")
(markup-crossref-list :class "malexpex" :sep ",\,")
(markup-crossref-layer :open "(\myhyper{" :close "})" :class "malexpex")

(define-crossref-class "malchapter")
(markup-crossref-list :class "malchapter" :sep ",\,")
(markup-crossref-layer :open "[\myhyper{" :close "}]" :class "malchapter")
\end{filecontents*}

% Redefinition in common index... (one-way approach)
\def\myhyperlink#1{\hyperlink{#1}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1|myhyperlink{\ep@rawexnoprint}}{\ep@rawexnoprint}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{\ep@rawexnoprint}{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{#1}}}}%
\makeatother

% A new index file...
\makeatletter
\let\temphere=\ep@rawexnoprint
\makeatother
\newwrite\myindexfile
\immediate\openout\myindexfile=\jobname.myi
\def\myhyper#1{\myhypertemp #1 }
\def\myhypertemp #1-#2-#3 {\hyperlink{#3}{\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{#3-to-index}}#1}}
% Two-way approach...
\newcount\mycounter 
\mycounter=0
\def\myshipping#1#2{%
  \global\advance\mycounter by 1%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{\the\mycounter}{}}%
  \hyperlink{\the\mycounter-to-index}{#1}%
  \immediate\write\myindexfile{\string\indexentry{#1|\material{#2-\thepage-\the\mycounter}}{\thepage}}%
  }% End of \myshipping...

% Regular definitions to be used in document body...
\def\pageindex#1{\def\material{malpage}\myshipping{#1}{\thepage}}
\def\expexindex#1{\def\material{malexpex}\myshipping{#1}{\temphere}}
\def\chapterindex#1{\def\material{malchapter}\myshipping{#1}{\thechapter}}

\begin{document}
% The form of \ex...\xe rewritten to the form of \ex... only
% We are hacking the end of the line...
\catcode`\^^M=13
\def^^M{\par}
\let\extemp=\ex
\def\ex#1^^M{\extemp#1\xe}

%\gathertags
\chapter{First chapter}
Some initial text.

\chapter{Second chapter}
The first approach.

\ex Bratwurst --- this example is followed by \index{Bratwurst} 
\ex Sauerkraut --- this example is followed by \index{Sauerkraut}
\ex By \index{Striz}
\ex By \index{Oldman}

\ex an experiment \chapterindex{on purpose}
\ex hello 1 \pageindex{paja}
\ex hello 2 \pageindex{malipivo}
\ex hello 3 \expexindex{next a}
\ex hello 4 \expexindex{more a}
\ex hello 5 \chapterindex{next b}
\ex hello 6 \chapterindex{more b}
\ex hello 7 \expexindex{paja}
\ex hello 8 \chapterindex{paja}
\ex finish \index{Sleep}

% A common index...
%\begingroup % Redefinition of \indexname...
%\def\thispagestyle#1{}%
\def\indexname{Common index\\ with example numbers\\(one-way traffic)}
\printindex

% An improved version of index...
\def\indexname{Index of\\ page, (exercise), [chapter]\\(two-way traffic)}
\immediate\closeout\myindexfile
\IfFileExists{\jobname.iym}{\input \jobname.iym}{}%
%\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 3: two-way traffic]

Comment: Thank you belatedly for the effort that went into this answer.  This is neater than the hack that I've been deploying, namely, of using hyphen to separate chapter and example numbers [e.g., (2-1)], letting `makeidx` compile that (it doesn't object), then opening up the `.idn` file and doing a search and replace of hyphen for dot.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post a solution that amounts to the same thing, but which may be a bit simpler. It uses the `index` package. You can instruct `index` to use a specific macro (below, `\PageExample`) to generate a reference in the index. Below I have it printing entries in the format "Page-Example" (e.g., 2-7). A different format is discussed below.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expex,lipsum,index}
% use this definition if using makeindex
\newcommand{\PageExample}{\thepage-\the\excnt}
% use this definition if using xindy
% \newcommand{\PageExample}{\thepage (\the\excnt)}
\newindex[PageExample]{my-index}{idx}{ind}{My Custom Index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\ex \lipsum[1]\index[my-index]{First example} \xe

\ex \lipsum[2] \index[my-index]{Second example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[3] \index[my-index]{Third example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[4] \index[my-index]{Fourth example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[5] \index[my-index]{Fifth example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[6] \index[my-index]{Sixth example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[6] \index[my-index]{Seventh example}\xe

\printindex[my-index]
\end{document}
```

The punctuation that can occur in the index references is limited by `makeindex`. If you're happy with the format "2-7" the above example works perfectly.

If you use `xindy` to process the index there is more flexibility. I wanted references like this "Page-number (Example-number)" i.e., 2(7). It's easy to generate that with the alternate definition of `\PageExample` above, but the index file then needs to be processed by `xindy`.

After compiling with `latex`, I invoke `xindy` as follows:

```
texindy -L english example.idx -M page-example.xdy
```

The file `page-example.xdy` instructs `xindy` about my "Page-number (Example-number)" format. It contains just one line:

```
(define-location-class "page-example" ("arabic-numbers" :sep "(" "arabic-numbers" :sep ")" ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying \thepage turned out not be a good idea, for reasons stated below.  So instead I now write to the .idx file directly.

The main problem remaining is that makeindex only recognizes {-} as a delimiter, not {.}.  Also, the counter \excnt is incremented AFTER it is used instead of BEFORE it is used.

Following Nicoloa Talbot's advice I was able to fix the delimeter problem.  Note that I have windows installed on drive G, which is probably not the case for anyone else.

First I copied and renamed an ist file from G:\programfiles\MikTex 2.9\makeindex as "period.ist".  Any subdirectory will do.  I also edited it to consist of

page_compositor "."

Then I used the Build/Define Output Profiles menu from TeXnic Center to add -s "period.ist" to the Makeindex argument list.  If any of these steps are not done correctly (for your installation) then Makeindex will not work.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{expex} 

\lingset{aboveexskip=0pt,glspace=1em plus .5em minus.2em,   
glrightskip=0pt plus 8em,aboveglftskip=0pt,glneveryline={\it},   
glstyle=nlevel,everygl={\hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1},   
exnotype=chapter.arabic}

\usepackage{makeidx}    
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ExIndex}[1]% same as \index
{%
 \immediate\write\@indexfile
            {\string\indexentry{#1}%
            {\thechapter.\the\excnt}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}    

\gathertags

\chapter{First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\ExIndex{Bratwurst} 
\ex Bratwurst --- this example is preceded by \verb"\ExIndex{Bratwurst}"
\xe 

\ExIndex{Sauerkraut}
\ex Sauerkraut --- this example is preceded by \verb"\ExIndex{Sauerkraut}" 
\xe 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: index]

Comment: The write to the external file is deferred, so by the time the line is written, `\thepage` has switched back to `\arabic{page}`, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess it must wait until the end of the page.  So one would have to have \thepage give a different answer each time it is called (in sequence).  Ugh!

Comment: The delimiter can be changed to a full stop by creating a `.ist` file (for example `mystyle.ist`) and adding the line `page_compositor "."` (and you need to specify the style using the `-s` switch when you run `makeindex`)

Comment: @Nicola Talbot - One thing windows will NOT let you do is create a file with a specific extension.  Instead I wind up creating mystyle.ist.tex.  If I have an .ist file, I can copy and edit it, so do you know where I can download one or could you email me one?

Comment: Never mind, I found one in MikTeX

Comment: I haven't used Windows in years, so someone may be able to correct me if I'm wrong, but I think if you specify a file name within double quotes in a 'Save As' dialog box, it will honour the extension you've used and not try adding the default extension to it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm still trying to come up with something myself.  I've upvoted in the meantime.