# How to automatically generate a list of linguistic examples with package linguex?

Tags: indexing, linguistics

I am using the `linguex` package to present linguistic examples. However, I would like to make an appendix at the end which contains all the examples I've used and the page information.

I am asking whether there exists any automatic way for that?

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please post a minimum working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), which solvers could compile? It would help them a lot!

Comment: You issue is solvable by creating an index. There is a problem called `makeindex` in the LaTeX software bundle that takes care of automatically created indexes. Google or TeX.SX will help you to get an index working.

Comment: And if you add a MWE of the way you are using `linguex`- as @Malipivo alredy suggested - the SX-community could try to find ways to make this specific index work better.

Comment: @Ruben I prefer to think of `makeindex` as part of the solution rather than part of the problem ;).

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165579/index-that-picks-up-on-example-numbers-not-page-numbers?rq=1?

Comment: I would probably use the `table` or `figure` floating environment or I would create a new one. The [`newfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package is a starting point for you.

Comment: @cfr I must have been unclear with my last statement. I regard `makeindex` totally as part of the solution.

Comment: @Ruben Not really unclear. It is just that you wrote 'There is a problem called `makeindex`...' whereas I assumed you meant 'There is a programme called `makeindex`...'. I was just amused by the typo. (Little things...)

Comment: @cfr Haha, perception is a strange thing. I don't got that til yet...