# Replace page numbers in index by theorem numbers

Tags: numbering, theorems, indexing, makeindex

I would like to create an index that refers to theorem numbers instead of the page numbers.

The following example creates the usual index with page numbers:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is about apples \index{apple} and bananas\index{banana}.
\end{theorem} 

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is about apples \index{apple} and pies\index{pie}.
\end{theorem} 

\newpage

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is about bananas\index{banana}.
\end{theorem} 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

> Index
>   apple, 1
>   banana, 1, 2
>   pie, 1

However, I would need the theorem numbers in the index instead, i.e.

> Index
>   apple, 1, 2
>   banana, 1, 3
>   pie, 2

Has anyone an idea how to do this?
Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165579/index-that-picks-up-on-example-numbers-not-page-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\index` writes out the value of `\thepage`. Just change it to `\thetheorem`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@wrindex{\thepage}{\thetheorem}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is about apples\index{apple} and bananas\index{banana}.
\end{theorem} 

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is about apples\index{apple} and pies\index{pie}.
\end{theorem} 

\newpage

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is about bananas\index{banana}.
\end{theorem} 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you change the value to \thethorem? Because if I execute your code, I still get an index showing the page numbers.

Comment: @Jack Really? The exact code?

Comment: Yes. And if I compare your code with mine, the only difference I can identify is that you have deleted the "ngerman" from the documentclass

Comment: @Jack In the example code, `ngerman` does nothing at all, except printing a warning on the console. Maybe you added `babel`?

Comment: It is fine, that you have removed `ngerman`. But still, how did you change the value of the index from `\thepage` to `\thetheorem` - I do not find this part in your code.

Comment: @Jack I am *deeply* sorry! Too late in the night and I didn't copy it right.